# Pass df_print an arbitrary function when knitting in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

When using `rmarkdown` to knit a document in RStudio, I want to use a particular function to print a `data.frame` (in my case, `pander` to get a multiline table). The `rmarkdown` package documentation says that, in addition to the four valid methods that can be passed to `df_print`, I can also pass it an arbitrary function:

> In addition to the named methods you can also pass an arbitrary function to be used for printing data frames.

I want to set the `df_print` option in the YAML header:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    df_print: pander
```

However, when using the Knit button in RStudio, it errors, saying:

```
Error: Invalid value for df_print (valid values are default, kable, tibble, paged
Execution halted
```

But, when I call the `render` function directly:

```
render("example.Rmd", pdf_document(df_print = pander))
```

The document renders just fine, and I get the PDF file I want. Is RStudio inserting itself into the knitting process when I use the Knit button in a way that it doesn't when I just call `render` directly? Why can't I pass an arbitrary function in the YAML header as well?

I also tried passing `pander::pander`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the evaluation of an expression in the YAML header using `!expr`:

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    df_print: !expr pander::pander
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [RLesur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190736/19332713), I could not get the same to work for `reactable` in a HTML document.

To do so, I followed [this response](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-cookbook/issues/186#issuecomment-569466829) to a related Github Issue which amounts to:

1. Set the option `rmarkdown.df_print = FALSE` in your .Rprofile file
   I ran `usethis::edit_r_profile("project")` and put the statement above within `options()`
2. Call `knit_print.data.frame <- function(x, ...){ knitr::knit_print( your_func(x), ... ) }` in your setup (or first) chunk